# PHP class not found but it's included

Tags: php

I'm including a PHP class with

```
require_once($ENGINE."/classUser.php");
```

but when the code is executed i receive this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebName\resources\engine\ajax\signup.php on line 12

I still can't figure out what's the problem. I'm 99% sure it's correct.

The "$ENGINE" is correct, and the class is correct too (Netbeans suggests me class methods and variables).

signup.php:

```
<?php

/* Created on: 13/12/2011
 * Author: 
 * 
 * Description: User signup procedure.
 */

require_once("../settings.php");
require_once($ENGINE."/classUser.php");

$user = new User();
$user->createUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"]);


?>
```

classUser.php:

```
<?php

/* Created on: 13/12/2011
 * Author: 
 * 
 * Description: This class manages users.
 */

require_once("settings.php");
require_once($LIBRARY."/cassandraphp/cassandra.php");

class User {

    public function createUser($username, $email, $password){
        $cassandra = Cassandra::createInstance($CASSANDRASERVER);
        $cassandra->set(
                "user.".$username,
                array(
                    'ID' => uniqid(),
                    'Username' => $username,
                    'Email' => $email,
                    'Password' => $password
                )
        );
    } 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all check if `$ENGINE."/classUser.php"` is a valid name of existing file.
Try this:

```
var_dump(file_exists($ENGINE."/classUser.php"));
```

Comment: Useless... require_once() will kill the script with a fatal error if the file can't be found or read.

Answer (score 61):

Check to make sure your environment isn't being picky about your opening tags. My configuration requires:

```
<?php
```

If I try to use:

```
<?
```

Then I get the same error as you.

Short tags can be enabled through the INI setting [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: If you dont have access to php.ini, you can add this to .htaccess:
php_value short_open_tag 1

Answer (score 37):

```
if ( ! class_exists('User')) 
    die('There is no hope!');
```

Answer (score 36):

I had this problem and the solution was namespaces. The included file was included in its own namespace. Obvious thing, easy to overlook.

Answer (score 14):

It may also be, that you by mistake commented out such a line like require_once `__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`   --- your namespaces are not loaded.

Or you forget to add a classmap to the composer, thus classes are not autoloaded and are not available. For example,

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "dir/YourClass.php",
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
```

Answer (score 3):

My fail might be useful to someone, so I thought I would post as I finally figured out what the issue was. I was autoloading classes like this:

```
define("PROJECT_PATH", __DIR__);

// Autoload class definitions
function my_autoload($class) {
    if(preg_match('/\A\w+\Z/', $class)) {
        include(PROJECT_PATH . '/classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
```

In my /classes folder I had 4 classes:

```
dbobject.class.php
meeting.class.php
session.class.php
user.class.php
```

When I later created a new class called:

```
cscmeeting.class.php
```

I started getting the `can't load DbObject class`. I simply could not figure out what was wrong. As soon as I deleted `cscmeeting.class.php` from the directory, it worked again.

I finally realized that it was looping through the directory alphabetically and prior to `cscmeeting.class.php` the first class that got loaded was `cscmeeting.class.php` since it started with `D`. But when I add the new class, which starts with `C` it would load that first and it extended the `DbObject` class. So it chocked every time.

I ended up naming my `DbObject` class to `_dbobject.class.php` and it always loads that first.

I realize my naming conventions are probably not great and that's why I was having issues. But I'm new to OOP so doing my best.

Answer (score 2):

The problem went away when I did

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

you should declare namespace in the ClassUser.php, something like this:

```
<?php
namespace app; // where 'app' is a folder declared as a root for the project
class ClassUser{
public function test(){
//log something here
}
}
?>
```

Then you can add the class in your other php files like this:

```
<?php
use app\ClassUser;
$classUserLcl = new ClassUser();
$classUserLcl->test();
?>
```

and you are done.
Otherwize it will abuse:

You Oh! its a **Fatal error :  Uncaught Error: Class 'app\ClassUser' not found in ...**

Answer (score 1):

As a more systematic and structured solution you could define folders where your classes are stored and create an autoloader (`__autoload()`) which will search the class files in defined places:

```
require_once("../settings.php");
define('DIR_CLASSES', '/path/to/the/classes/folder/'); // this can be inside your settings.php

$user = new User();
$user->createUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"]);

function __autoload($classname) { 
    if(file_exists(DIR_CLASSES . 'class' . $classname . '.php')) {
        include_once(DIR_CLASSES . 'class' . $classname . '.php'); // looking for the class in the project's classes folder
    } else {
        include_once($classname . '.php'); // looking for the class in include_path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It 'happened to me!
The problem is that somehow you include a file with the same file name of the class thus invalidating the same class!

Check the path of inclusion and these checks files with the same name!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `file permissions` for the correct linux user for `classUser.php`

Answer (score 1):

When namespace declaration is part of your php class file *"this kind of weird errors tends to appear"*.

**Solution**: Use `namespace` with `{`, your code shows like this:

```
<?php

namespace path_to\lib {

require_once "folder/php_class_file_where_namespace_declaration_is_part_of_it.php";

**YOUR CODE HERE**

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check `File Permissions`
2. Check `File size`.

Sometimes an inaccessible or corrupted file would be the problem, as was in my case

Answer (score 0):

Double check your autoloader's requirements & namespaces.

- For example, does your autoloader require your namespace to match the
  folder structure of where the file is located? If so, make sure they
  match.
- Another example, does your autoloader require your filenames to
  follow a certain pattern/is it case sensitive? If so, make sure the
  filename follows the correct pattern.
- And of course if the class is in a namespace make sure to include it
  properly with a fully qualified class name (`/Path/ClassName`) or with a `use` statement at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is how you use new User().
Set path something like

```
$user = new \resources\engine\ajax\User();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've included the file correctly and file exists and still getting error:

Then make sure:
Your included file contains the class and is not defined within any namespace.
If the class is in a namespace then:
instead of `new YourClass()` you've to do `new YourNamespace\YourClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happen in cases when use a trait or extend a class, you should be aware to instantiate the class after the class declaration for example:

This example will trigger class not found error:

```
$class = new A();

class A {
   use SomeTrait;
}
```

To make it to work move the initialization step in the bottom like so:

```
class A {
   use SomeTrait;
}

$class = new A();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to use the use keyword, as well as the include statement. Tested it with either missing, and it doesn't work.

```
namespace foo;
use src\config\object;
include('config/object.php');
```