# PHP Class not found even though file exists

Tags: php, class, require, file-exists

I've researched this and found other questions ([PHP class not found but it's included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490667/php-class-not-found-but-its-included)) but they don't answer this stupidly simple problem!

Here's the error: `Class 'Functions' not found in /public_html/sites/sitename/index.php`

My folder structure is like this:

```
public_html/assests/php/functions.php //class
```

I `require_once` this file from here: `public_html/sites/sitename/index.php`

I've checked the `file_exists`, of course it does else `require_once` would fail. What is going on?!

Here's my code (just in case I've missed something really dumb...)

```
    require_once('../../assets/php/functions.php'); 

    if( file_exists('../../assets/php/functions.php') ){
        error_log('Of course it exists!');
    }
    else{
        error_log('Oh dear...');
    }

    $fn = new Functions();
```

Contents of functions.php (edited for brevity):

```
class Functions{    

    public function functions(){
        //constructor
    }

    //pretty print
    public function pp($str){
        return '<pre class="pre-show prettyprint">'.htmlentities($str).'</pre>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: @CodeGodie it's not a filepath issue, the file exists from where I am calling it.

Comment: This should work. Its working locally for me. Perhaps you are not showing all your code. Are there any files or configurations that may be different?

Comment: what do you get when you run this: `var_dump(file_get_contents('../../assets/php/functions.php'));`

Answer (score 2):

You have a misspelling, an extra `s` in 'assets':

> ```
> My folder structure is like this:
>
> public_html/assests/php/functions.php //class
> ```

Make sure your file name is **"assets"** and make sure your `require` matches that:

```
require_once('../../assets/php/functions.php');
```