# Fatal Error PHP Class not found but it's included in the project

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to test Stripe Checkout on my virtual server but when i try return this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Customer' not found in
> /home/user/public_html/charge.php on line 8

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490667/php-class-not-found-but-its-included) I verified if the file ./config.php was existing with:

> var_dump(file_exists("./config.php"));

It returns `bool(true)` being a PhP beginner im not sure what i'm doing wrong.

**charge.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');
  
  var_dump(file_exists("./config.php"));
  
  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 2000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $20.00!</h1>';


?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/stripe/init.php');
$stripe = array(
  secret_key      => getenv('sk_test_PidozakrX1NIEf8YM9TBDMl8'),
  publishable_key => getenv('pk_test_pCzekEHR4Io5YFJhrzFE7Koe')
);
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

**Directory:**

> ```
> >public_html
>    >vendor
>        >stripe
>           >lib
>               >Charge.php
>               >Customer.php
>               >Stripe.php
> ```

**UPDATE**
Okay so with changes suggested by Matthew getting new error. But i'm not sure where should I set the API key `Stripe::setApiKey(<API-KEY>)`? It's aleady set in `config.php`...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\Authentication' with
> message 'No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using
> "Stripe::setApiKey()".in
> /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php:127 Stack
> trace: #0
> /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(59):
> Stripe\ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/customers', Array,
> Array) #1
> /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(115):
> Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customers', Array, Array) #2
> /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(155):
> Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/customers', Array,
> NULL) #3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/Customer.php(37):
> Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL) #4
> /home/user/public_html/charge.php(9): Stripe\Customer::create(Array)
>
> ## 5 {main} thrown in /home/user/public_html/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 127

Comment: does it work if you just do \Stripe\Customer::create(... ?

Comment: I hope those aren't your live Stripe credentials...

Comment: @Machavity: of couse not loll! You hungry huh?

Comment: @MatthewArkin: thank you for trying! Still return same error... `Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Customer' not found`

Comment: `\vendor\stripe\lib\Customer::create` is not how you access namespaced classes - it should be what Matthew posted above.

Comment: Ensure you're using a slash in front

Comment: getenv('sk_test_PidozakrX1NIEf8YM9TBDMl8') also looks odd, the name you pass to getenv should be the name of the environment variable eg getenv("stripe_secret_key") would return the value of the environment variable with the name stripe_secret_key

Comment: and assuming you're on any new version of the Stripe api you should be doing require_once('vendor/stripe/init.php');

Comment: @MatthewArkin: Thanks a lot. We're moving up! I have changed the new path. Now i'm getting new error... I will update my post.

Comment: @MatthewArkin: updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I emailed stripe support. I could of never figured the answer out...! So turns out the issue here is the way I've setup the API keys in `config.php`. This code will not do what we think... It's trying to retrieve an environment variable set with the variable name as the API key which will just return an empty string...

**config.php**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/stripe/init.php');
$stripe = array(
  secret_key      => getenv('sk_test_PidozakrX1NIEf8YM9TBDMl8'),
  publishable_key => getenv('pk_test_pCzekEHR4Io5YFJhrzFE7Koe')
);
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

**should be**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/stripe/init.php');
$stripe = array(
  secret_key      => ('sk_test_PidozakrX1NIEf8YM9TBDMl8'),
  publishable_key => ('pk_test_pCzekEHR4Io5YFJhrzFE7Koe')
);
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

Basically, just remove `getenv` after each arrow. For me it works! The customer is created and the amount is charged! Nothing fancy. Simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it looks like due to the composer,
 
 If you haven't check path yet , please first look them  in *composer.json*

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Sub-folder/path": "class's parent directory "
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If the problem occurs due to this one , You should re-install websocket
**OR** you can arrange path to this structure

Comment: hey I give you props for trying but I have emailed stripe and turns out the answer was pretty simple. I'm posting the answer.