# PHP: Class not found tcpdf wrong path

Tags: php, tcpdf

I got some SVG-Charts and now I want to be able to download them as a PDF-File from my website. To do so I want to use TCPDF. I have required the file of the library and give out the used path, also I used "class_exists('TCPDF')". Both return the right value. Still, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kanboard\Controller\TCPDF' not found in C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\app\Controller\ExportController.php:172 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\app\Controller\ExportController.php(117): Kanboard\Controller\ExportController->downoadPDF(Array) #1 C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\app\Core\Controller\Runner.php(77): Kanboard\Controller\ExportController->summaryPDF() #2 C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\app\Core\Controller\Runner.php(31): Kanboard\Core\Controller\Runner->executeController() #3 C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\index.php(13): Kanboard\Core\Controller\Runner->execute() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\fftboard\app\Controller\ExportController.php on line 172

This is strange, since the class is not 'Kanboard\Controller\TCPDF' but 'Kanboard\Analytic\TCPDF'. Has this something to do with the namespace? I do not know, why it can not find the class, if the file is required correctly.
Some code of the file:

```
namespace Kanboard\Controller;
class ExportController extends BaseController
{
  public function downoadPDF($project)
  {
    $tcpdfPath = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../../libs/tcPDF/TCPDF-master/TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');
    require_once $tcpdfPath;
    $log .=  class_exists('TCPDF');
    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
  }
}
```

In "PHP class not found but it's included" the Problem is **not** solved. The answer marked as solutin just tells you to check if the File exists and it does. The other solutions suggests to use `<?php` instead of `<?`, which I already did bevore and to check if the Class exists, which it did, as I said above.

Can somebody explain to me why this error appears?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP class not found but it's included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490667/php-class-not-found-but-its-included)

Comment: @Kris Roofe the Problem seems quite similar, but the answers do not help me, since I tried them without success.

Comment: Can you not use composer and this? https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF Then you can autoload the TCPDF library

Comment: @Chris Hemmens I can not download it, because it is blockt from a Internet-security progrmm of my employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare:

```
namespace Kanboard\Controller;
```

all *partially-qualified* class names will be taken relative to that name. Your code here:

```
new TCPDF(...)
```

uses a partially-qualified class name -- since it doesn't start with a `\` -- so, it's resolved to `Kanboard\Controller\TCPDF`.

You've stated it should be `Kanboard\Analysis\TCPDF`, but I'm not so sure based on how the code is written. Try updating your code to either of these:

```
new \TCPDF(...)
new \Kanboard\Analysis\TCPDF(...)
```

Replace the `...` with the actual arguments. If the first works, then TCPDF is in the *root* namespace (which I suspect). If the second works, then it's in the namespace you stipulate.